# Spectrum error: Parquet file schema is fine but for some reason it fails while copying

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I have a file in S3 that I'm trying to copy into a Redshift schema, the command I'm using is:

```sql
copy schema.table
from 'path/to/my/s3'
iam_role 'role'
format as parquet;
```

The schema, according to (Scala) Spark (I'm reading the file and then printing the schema) is:

```
channel_id string
created_at timestamp
source string <- this is a new column
sent_to string
received_at timestamp
sender_last_read timestamp
```

My redshift table definition:

```
channel_id char(100)
created_at timestamp,
source varchar(256) <- also tried text and char
received_at timestamp
sender_last_read timestamp
```

But whenever I try to copy the file I get the following error:

```
Spectrum Scan Error. File 'path/to/my/s3' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column path/to/my/s3/.source. Column type: VARCHAR, Parquet schema: optional int96 sender_last_read [i:6 d:1 r:0]
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. It seems that the column source it actually IS a varchar.

Any idea?

I tried switching the column types, but varchar and char is not fixing the issue.

Edit: And I don't even understand why the error message has 2 different columns...

Comment: Looks like something wrong with an order of columns in table and in file.
Do you create your redshift table from zero or alter it and add additional column?

Comment: looks like table def is missing a `sent_to` column?